# Ни то чихнув, ни то пролаяв

Tags: пунктуация

Ворд требует запятую после "то". На мой взгляд ставить её нет причины. Как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте: "**Не** то чихнув, **не** то пролаяв"

Comment: Тоже самое

Comment: Странно "не то .. не то" - "стандартный" сочинительный союз, который Ворд должен знать

Comment: Ну там с деепричастием же. Это вызывает у него трудности. И вызывает у меня замешательство.

Comment: Честно говоря, не вижу разницы.

Comment: Да, greydog, прав!  Частица не входит в состав сочинительных союзов: не то; не то -  не то; не только -  но; не то что не -  а; не то чтобы не -  а, например: Наверху за потолком кто-то не то стонет, не то смеется (Чехов). У партизан были не только винтовки, но и пулеметы (Ставский). ( Грамота.ру).

Answer (score 2):

Ворд не всегда прав. Ворд видит соотносительное слово ТО, которое в составе союзов часто отделяется запятой, поэтому и требует запятую. Ср.: Это то, что нужно. А я тебе говорю, что если ты поедешь, ***то*** я поеду с тобой. 
Запятая ставится между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством повторяющихся союзов: **и...и, да...да, то...то, ли...ли, или...или и т. п.**, например: ***Легкий ветерок то просыпался, то утихал. (Тургенев).***
Поэтому в вашем случае запятая перед ***то*** лишняя.

Comment: А какая у вас версия Ворда? У меня - 2007. Я написал это предложение в Ворде, но Ворд не потребовал запятой.

Comment: У меня 2003 ворд

Answer (score 2):

В Ворде только основные правила, нюансов нет, не всегда нужно ему верить. У меня тоже подчеркнул ТО. Когда нажала на проверку грамотности, выдал обособление деепричастного оборота. Значит, союза он не увидел. Да он частенько выдаёт неверное написание, не стоит обращать внимание, Вы же уверены в своей правоте - пишите, как подсказывает ваше чувство языка.

Comment: На чувство надейся, а правила знай))